Is the volume of the image of the moment map an invariant of a symplectic toric manifold?
Given a symplectic toric manifold is known that the image of the moment map is a Delzant polytope that fully characterises the manifold. What about the volume of the polytope? Is it possible that two symplectic toric manifolds have polytopes with the same volume but different shapes? For circle actions naturally the length of the 1-dimensional polytope also fully characterises the manifold.

The volume of the polytope is equal to the symplectic volume up to a factor of $n!$ ($n= \dim(M)/2$) by the Duistermaat-Heckman formula. Scaling the polytope is equivalent to scaling the symplectic form, so without further assumptions any symplectc toric manifold can have any volume.
